# Knowledge Base with decision tree for procedures

Tags: knowledge-base

I'm looking for some knowledge base tool that enable me to display procedures in a decision tree fashion. It must run in browser (chrome at least), windows client but can be hosted in linux or windows server.

Something like [Yonix](http://corp.yonyx.com/), but open source :)